# how to retrive a list from the firebase database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

this is my db structure
[image]

I have a list of passenger and i want to retrive them from the firebase database if the passenger list contains more than one passenger then i want to get those data show in one textView. But everytime it generates 2 textView if there were two passenger. I want in all cases it shows all the data in just one TextView.

This is my model Class`

```
     public class RetrieveTickets {
       private String name;
       private String age;
       private String gender;
        public RetrieveTickets() {
      }

    public RetrieveTickets(String name, String age, String gender) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.gender = gender;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }
    public List<HashMap<String,Object>> toList(){
        List<HashMap<String,Object>> list=new ArrayList<>();
        HashMap<String,Object> map=new HashMap<>();
        map.put("name",getName());
        map.put("age",getAge());
        map.put("gender",getGender());
        list.add(map);
        return list;
    }

}
```

this is MyActivity where i am showing the data

```
public class MyBookingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<RetrieveTickets, BookingHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter;
public static  List<String> trips=new ArrayList<>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_bookings);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_bookings);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
   String tripId = getIntent().getStringExtra("TripId");
    trips.add(tripId);
   // String bookingId = getIntent().getStringExtra("BookingId");
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    String userId = user.getUid();
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        Query query = databaseReference.child("BooKings").child(userId).child(tripId).child("passenger");
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<RetrieveTickets> firebaseRecyclerOptions = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<RetrieveTickets>()
                .setQuery(query, RetrieveTickets.class)
                .build();

        firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<RetrieveTickets, BookingHolder>(firebaseRecyclerOptions) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BookingHolder holder, int position, @NonNull RetrieveTickets model) {
                                                holder.setPassengers(model);
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public BookingHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.tickets, parent, false);
                return new BookingHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                super.onError(error);
                Toast.makeText(MyBookingsActivity.this,"error"+error,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };

    recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (firebaseRecyclerAdapter != null) {
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter.stopListening();
    }
}
public static class BookingHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private TextView passenger;
    public BookingHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        passenger=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.passenger);
    }
    void setPassengers(RetrieveTickets retrieveTickets) {
        passenger.setText(retrieveTickets.toList().toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: you want all passengers will be displayed on one TexVtiew but you use RecyclerView, why?

Comment: there might be multiple bookings related to a user ,as you might have seen the structure of my database @MohsenCadir

Comment: Post your holder/adapter class for the recycler view

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display all passengers in one TextView then you shouldn't do like this... Right now you are using RecyclerView and it will make **rows == number of passengers** and its exactly why we use RecyclerView

If you want to show PassengerList in one textView do like this

```
StringBuilder passengerStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for (String details : yourList) {
   passengerStrBuilder.append(details + "\n");
}
textView.setText(passengerStrBuilder.toString());
```

Here **yourList** is *Passenger List*

Comment: it generates two recylerView items for two passengers...I want if they belong to one List the there should be only one textView and details of both the passengers would appear inside one TextView @devROYAL